# How can I enter a set of values into a column, but without changing the pre-existing entries?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, select

I need to add the columns+row entries for a new set of data that was given to me, to an older set of data.

I am quite new to SQL, but have been using

```
SELECT
, Ltrim(Rtrim([Column1_New_Table]))              AS        [Column1_Old_Table]
, Ltrim(Rtrim([Column2_New_Table]))              AS        [Column2_Old_Table]
               ...
               ...
FROM dbo.Old_Table
```

Now, a certain column in the new table is missing, but I know what value it needs to take (it is the integer 103). How can I update my old table with this set of values, but only corresponding to the new set of data?

Ideally, I want the final output to look like

```
Col1 | Col 2 | ... | ID_Number (desired update column)
...     ...    ...     ...  {old table info}
...     ...    ...     ...  {old table info}
...     ...    ...     ...  {old table info}
...     ...    ...     103  {new table info}
...     ...    ...     103  {new table info}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. 
But let's assume:

**Old_Table**

```
Col1    Col2    ID_Number
a       a       (null)
b       b       (null)
c       c       (null)
d       d       (null)
```

**New_Table**

```
Col1    Col2    ID_Number
c       c       (null)
d       d       (null)
```

The below `merge` will do the job.

```
merge into 
 Old_Table O using  New_Table N
 on (O.Col1 = N.Col1 and 
     O.Col2 = N.Col2)
when matched then
 update set ID_number = 103 ;
```

Replace on `(O.Col1 = N.Col1 and  O.Col2 = N.Col2)` in merge to your primary key columns.

After that **Old_Table**

```
Col1    Col2    ID_Number
a       a       (null)
b       b       (null)
c       c       103
d       d       103
```

Here you can find [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8f276/5/0) with sample